# Webpack copyFiles duplicating files from subdirectory into main directory

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-encore

I have a directory for images as follows:

[image]

Within the icons sub directory I have SVGs to organize the structure.

Within webpack, I specify the following:

```
.copyFiles({
     from: './assets/images',
     to: '[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
     context: './assets'
})
```

What happens in the build is as follows:

[image]

What happens here is it copies all of the icons within the directory and copies it directly into the images directory while also copies the icons directory. It does it twice. Is there a reason why this happens? How do I ensure that it doesn't copy the content twice within webpack?

Comment: I had the same problem. Turns out, all files that are used in scss/js files ended up in the root of the build folder (handled by webpacks assets modules).  These files live in the same folder that is copied by copyFiles. Hence the duplicates. So only files that are used in scss/js are duplicated. At least in my case. Don't really have a solution. Tried to align the paths with `Encore.configureImageRule()` but could't make it work; but that's probably the way to go. Or, if that makes sense in your project, have separate asset folders for the files you copy and the once you use in scss/js files.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to copy files?

Use the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) and specify **globs** in your paths.  Take a look at [this as a real working example](https://github.com/fluidtrends/papanache/blob/master/src/web/config.dev.js#L59)

In your case you would use a glob like `./assets/images/**/*` for the source and it should work as expected.

Comment: I'm using encore. That didn't work because it removed the directory. I don't want to remove the icon directory. I just want to remove the duplication in the base images folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration for images i've running on a project for a long time:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/,
    use: [ 
      {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
          name: '../img/[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

it copies the images to ./img/ folder

Comment: Have you tried changing file-loader to your installed file loader plugin? Or installing file-loader?

Comment: So webpack encore doesn't have a way of doing this then?

Comment: Don't really know, shitched to parcel some time ago. Only have legacy projects with webpack